# egrep + quantifier not working

Tags: regex, grep

egrep isn't matching in the following example and from everything I've read it should be. The expression is `'{% +'` what I'm trying to accomplish is match on all the `{% %}` brackets in my markdown files. From my current understanding it should match `{%` then one or more spaces after that, but fail to match if there is no space. I can use the same expression in PowerShell and it matches so I'm wondering what it is I'm missing.

Snippet to match against

```
{% highlight ruby %}
{% endhighlight %}

cat file.md | egrep '{% +'
```

Comment: In this case replace the `+` quantifier with a `*` quantifier. What is the problem?

Comment: * does work, but it also allows for no space. How could I ensure a space is present. I though that's what + would do, but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try removing `+` and see if it works. The quantifier is redundant since you need to match 1 or more. If there is 1, `'{% '` is already enough. Also, there may be a tab, not a space. Try `[[:blank:]]` instead of the literal space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, your regex works as expected.  Given an input file `file.md` containing:

```
{% highlight ruby %}
{% endhighlight %}
not this line, though
nor {%this%}
```

When I run your command (avoiding [UUoC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat/11710888#11710888)), I get the output shown:

```
$ egrep '{% +' file.md
{% highlight ruby %}
{% endhighlight %}
$
```

You've not identified which version of `egrep` you are using and which platform you are using it on.  I'm running Mac OS X 10.11.6 and using `egrep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD` (but I also get the same result with GNU Grep 2.25).

You should be aware, though, that `{` is a metacharacter to `egrep`, and the problem may be that it is not handling the initial `{` as you expect.

For example, here's a more complex `egrep` invocation that should only select the `endhighlight` line:

```
$ egrep '\{% {1,4}[a-z]{4,20} {1,4}%\}' file.md
{% endhighlight %}
$
```

I used the backslashes to escape the first and last braces.  The `{n,m}` notation means *n ≤ x ≤ m* matches of the preceding regex (blank and `[a-z]`).  You can omit `,m`; you can use `{4,}` too — check the manual to understand these.  However, on my machine, I can also run:

```
$ egrep '{% {1,4}[a-z]{4,20} {1,4}%}' file.md
{% endhighlight %}
$
```

Presumably, because the first `{` doesn't start an `{n,m}` sequence, it is treated as an ordinary character.

If you look at the POSIX specification for [Extended Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04), you'll find that it says using `{` like that is undefined behaviour:

> `*+?{`
>
> The `<asterisk>`, `<plus-sign>`, `<question-mark>`, and `<left-brace>` shall be special except when used in a bracket expression (see RE Bracket Expression). Any of the following uses produce undefined results:
>
> - If these characters appear first in an ERE, or immediately following a `<vertical-line>`, `<circumflex>`, or `<left-parenthesis>`
> - If a `<left-brace>` is not part of a valid interval expression (see EREs Matching Multiple Characters)

So, according to POSIX, you are using a regex that produces undefined results.  Therefore, you are getting a result that POSIX deems acceptable.

Clearly, you should be able to use the following and get the result you expect:

```
$ egrep '\{% +' file.md
{% highlight ruby %}
{% endhighlight %}
$
```

Comment: By using the escape "\"character on { and } I was able to get the + quantifier to work as I expected. I appreciate you pointing out that it's also a metacharacter. It makes complete sense now why it wasn't working before. I also greatly appreciate the long and detailed comment. It was extremely useful thank you.